# Exponential decay involving logarithm

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

> In 2011 reactor $X$ released $4.2$ times the amount of cesium-137 as was leaked during reactor $Y$ disaster in 1986?
>
> Using; A = Pert Half-life = $30.2$ years.
>
> a) What year will cesium-137 level be half as much as immediately after the 2011 $X$ disaster?
>
> b) In what year will cesium-137 level be a quarter as much as immediately after the 2011 $X$ disaster?
>
> c) How long after the disaster until cesium-137 levels are the same as immediately after the 1986 $Y$ disaster?

a) Answer: *2041* one half-life
b) Answer: *2071* two half-life
c) Answer: *0* immediate would have same levels therefore it's zero.

Are my answers correct if not what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

a and b are fine.  For c you need to cut it by a factor 4.2.

Comment: I read a) and b) as not involving Y at all, i.e., they are simply asking "when will the 2011 levels be at a half/a quarter the level it was at 2011?". If I may; why do you think it is otherwise?

Comment: I misread.  I agree with your answers for a and b.  I think c is still referring to 2011 and comparing it to 1986, but the wording is not clear on that point.

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct a and b are only involving reactor X as for C I'm confused on the wording as well but I belive it is referring to both reactor X and Y that would make sense for the 4.2 times the amount portion.

Answer (score 1):

Exponential decay follows the function $$N(t)=N_0 e^{kt}$$where $k$ is related to the half-life $t_{1/2}$ as $$N(t_{1/2})=\frac{N_0}{2}=N_0 e^{-kt_{1/2}} \leftrightarrow k=\frac{\ln(2)}{t_{1/2}}$$

(notice it is found as the time where the number of radioactive particles left are half of the original amount, namely $\frac{N_0}{2}$).

$a$ and $b$ look fine.

Now, for question $c)$, you want to find the time $t_c$ that the 2011 disaster (which was $4.2$ times as large as the 1986 one) has decayed to be at the same level as the 1986 disaster. This is the same as writing $$N(t_c)=\frac{N_0}{4.2}=N_0 e^{-kt_c}$$ which can be solved for $t_c$ using your knowledge of how $k$ is related to the half-life (which you know).